# C++ Making an array of pointers to objects(nodes) on Stack

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was trying to addEdge() to my nodes and I noticed that when i tried to access a "node" on the _nodes array it did not retain the values of the construction, for example like the id. It was suppose to be 1 and it is printing 4198441. Is this the correct way for initializing the array so that each position of it is pointing to a specific node? (I cant use the "new" keyword nor the "list" and "vector" library.)

This is how I am creating an array of Pointers to Nodes. 
Each position of the array _nodes[x] is suppose to be a pointer to a node.

```
  //array
  Node* _nodes[];

  //Constructor
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    Node node(i);          //i is the id of the future node.
    _nodes[i] = &node;
  }   



   void addEdge(int a,int b){
    std::cout<<"The id of the node stored in a is:" << _nodes[a]->getId();

    ...
}
```

This code belongs to an independent class called Graph.

Comment: You are storing pointers that are invalid once the `for` loop ends.

Comment: What is the alternative?

Comment: 1. Store objects instead of pointers, 2. Store pointers to dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: it seems like it is the only way...

Comment: Use objects as the first option. If you must user pointers, use smart pointers, not raw pointers.

Comment: Worth noting that `Node* _nodes[];` does not specify the array size. Bad things can only result from an array of undefined size, assuming the compiler allows it.

Comment: Help people help you. Post a [MCVE].

Comment: Why can't you use `new`/`std::vector`? Either the size if known at compile-time and you can just make an array of that size, or you should use some way to allocate the objects at run-time.

Answer (score -1):

```
_nodes[i] = &node;
```

This line stores a pointer to a local object. As soon as your function returns, the pointer gets to point to an invalid memory location as the object gets destroyed.

You could use `_nodes[i] = new Node(i);` (and drop the local object) but then you'll have to manage that memory and delete it, once done with it.

Comment: isnt there any other way without using the "new" keyword?

Comment: Global objects, but then it's a mess of keeping track of which objects are for what, unless you have only a few.

Comment: @user8848592 `std::unique_ptr<Node>` with `std::make_unique<Node>` or `std::vector<Node>` and stop storing pointers. [Docs on `std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). [Docs on `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @user4581301 what you suggest amounts to forcibly refactor the whole user's codebase without wondering whether it's under his control or the impact this may have. He asks how to store an object that won't become invalid. Maybe one should answer just that and not advocate rewritting the whole thing. Although, yeah smart_pointers and vectors are better than arrays of naked pointers

Comment: I'm not suggesting your answer is wrong. It could provide better options, but it is correct. My comment is in response to user8848592's request for a `new`-less way to do this.

Comment: @user4581301 my bad, makes sense, when view in that light.